# LINQ query slower after migrating from .net 4.8 to .net 6

Tags: sql, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I migrated my .net framework 4.8 EF6 mvc web app to .net6 EF core.
surprisingly, it seems that LINQ queries run slower on the migrated app.
I tested on my IIS server and on my local machine, in debug mode putting a brake point on the query.
this is the query:

```
List<Lead> RelevantLeads = (from l in db.Leads.Include("Campaign")
                                    where l.InsertionDateTime > fromDateMonths
                                    && l.Campaign.Provider.Company.CompanyID == companyId
                                    && l.Status == null
                                    && (l.User == null || l.UserID == user.UserID)
                                    && l.isSentToDialer == false
                                    select l).OrderBy(l => l.InsertionDateTime).ToList();
```

the migration required extensive work also making some changes to map the model to the DB. we put some attributes on the properties to map them correctly to the corresponding column in the DB. The model corresponds to the DB and return the correct results.

Example:

```
[Column("LeadType_LeadTypeID")]
```

If you have any Idea on what could lead to such odd behavior I will appreciate your input!

After monitoring the SQL server I found that the SQL queries the were generated were different.  though both yield the same result - the one that was generated from the old version took 4 seconds while the newer one took 8 seconds.

Please see the SQL queries.
From new code:

```
SELECT [l].[LeadID], [l].[Age], [l].[BecameClientDateTime], [l].[CRMLeadID], [l].[CampaignID], [l].[City], [l].[ClickId], [l].[Company_CompanyID], [l].[Country], [l].[Discriminator], [l].[Email], [l].[EmpResponseDifference], [l].[FirstName], [l].[ForwardToEmpDateTime], [l].[ForwardToEmpDifference], [l].[GeneralField1], [l].[GeneralField2], [l].[IdentificationNumber], [l].[InsertionDateTime], [l].[InterfacedSystemLeadPK], [l].[LastName], [l].[LastUpdateDateTime], [l].[LeadOpenedFirstTime], [l].[LeadTypeID], [l].[Location], [l].[MobilePhone], [l].[NotesFromLeadProvider], [l].[NotesToLeadProvider], [l].[Provider_ProviderID], [l].[ProviderLeadPK], [l].[SecondaryPhone], [l].[State], [l].[StatusID], [l].[StreetAddress], [l].[UserID], [l].[ZIPCode], [l].[isClient], [l].[isDNC], [l].[isMeetingHeld], [l].[isMeetingSet], [l].[isQuote], [l].[isQuoteViewed], [l].[isSentToCRM], [l].[isSentToDialer], [l].[isSuccessfullyInterfaced], [l].[utm_campaign], [l].[utm_content], [l].[utm_medium], [l].[utm_source], [l].[utm_term], [l].[AskingAmount], [l].[BusinessName], [l].[CreditCardSales], [l].[MonthlyGross], [l].[YearInBusiness], [l].[AgeOfYoungestDriver], [l].[Block], [l].[CarInsuranceType], [l].[CarRegistrationNumber], [l].[Experience], [l].[InjuryClaims], [l].[InsuranceStartDate], [l].[KmPerYear], [l].[LeviCode], [l].[LicenseRevocation], [l].[Manufacturer], [l].[Model], [l].[NumberOfClaims], [l].[Owner], [l].[PastInsurance], [l].[PermissionGroup], [l].[PolicyNumber], [l].[PropertyClaims], [l].[Riders], [l].[Usage], [l].[VehicleType], [l].[Year], [l].[lien], [l].[AppraisersName], [l].[ClaimNumber], [l].[DateOfIncident], [l].[GarageName], [l].[RegistrationNumber], [l].[ThirdPartyInsuranceCompany], [l].[Floor], [l].[HomeInsuranceType], [l].[SumContent], [l].[SumStructure], [l].[Sum], [l].[EmploymentStatus], [l].[Income], [l].[LoanPurpose], [l].[LoanRequestAmount], [l].[isChecksReturned], [l].[isCreditCard], [l].[LoanAmount], [l].[MortgageStartIn], [l].[Phase], [l].[CurrentInsuranceCompany], [l].[Floor1], [l].[MortgageInsuranceType], [l].[SquareMeters], [l].[StructureType], [c].[CampaignID], [c].[CampaignDescription], [c].[CampaignName], [c].[CostPerCampaign], [c].[CostPerLead], [c].[DID], [c].[DialerCampaign], [c].[DiallerRank], [c].[IsCheckInDNCListOnLeadInsertion], [c].[IsDeleteFromDNCListOnLeadInsertion], [c].[IsExtraDuplicateCheck], [c].[IsNewLeadDistribiuteFromDashboard], [c].[IsSpecificDuplicateCheck], [c].[IsSyncFromCRM], [c].[LeadType_LeadTypeID], [c].[NumOfDaysToCheckForDuplicates], [c].[ProviderID], [c].[ReferenceCampaignID], [c].[isAutoDialerOut], [c].[isTrigerInterfaceEnterence]
    FROM [Leads] AS [l]
    INNER JOIN [Campaigns] AS [c] ON [l].[CampaignID] = [c].[CampaignID]
    INNER JOIN [Providers] AS [p] ON [c].[ProviderID] = [p].[ProviderID]
    LEFT JOIN [Companies] AS [c0] ON [p].[Company_CompanyID] = [c0].[CompanyID]
    LEFT JOIN [Status] AS [s] ON [l].[StatusID] = [s].[StatusID]
    LEFT JOIN [Users] AS [u] ON [l].[UserID] = [u].[UserID]
    WHERE [l].[InsertionDateTime] > @__fromDateMonths_0 AND [c0].[CompanyID] = @__companyId_1 AND [s].[StatusID] IS NULL AND ([u].[UserID] IS NULL OR ([l].[UserID] = @__user_UserID_2)) AND  [l].[isSentToDialer] = CAST(0 AS bit)
    ORDER BY [l].[InsertionDateTime]
```

From old code:

```
SELECT 
[Project1].[LeadID] AS [LeadID], 
[Project1].[Discriminator] AS [Discriminator], 
[Project1].[LeadTypeID] AS [LeadTypeID], 
[Project1].[CampaignID] AS [CampaignID], 
[Project1].[ProviderLeadPK] AS [ProviderLeadPK], 
[Project1].[InsertionDateTime] AS [InsertionDateTime], 
[Project1].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], 
[Project1].[LastName] AS [LastName], 
[Project1].[MobilePhone] AS [MobilePhone], 
...
[Project1].[Provider_ProviderID] AS [Provider_ProviderID], 
[Project1].[Company_CompanyID] AS [Company_CompanyID]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Filter1].[LeadID] AS [LeadID], 
    [Filter1].[LeadTypeID] AS [LeadTypeID], 
    [Filter1].[CampaignID1] AS [CampaignID], 
    ... 
    [Filter1].[Company_CompanyID1] AS [Company_CompanyID], 
    [Extent4].[CampaignID] AS [CampaignID1], 
    ... 
    [Extent4].[ReferenceCampaignID] AS [ReferenceCampaignID], 
    [Extent4].[IsSyncFromCRM] AS [IsSyncFromCRM], 
    [Extent4].[LeadType_LeadTypeID] AS [LeadType_LeadTypeID]
    FROM   (SELECT [Extent1].[LeadID] AS [LeadID], [Extent1].[LeadTypeID] AS [LeadTypeID], [Extent1].[CampaignID] AS [CampaignID1], [Extent1].[ProviderLeadPK] AS [ProviderLeadPK], [Extent1].[InsertionDateTime] AS [InsertionDateTime], [Extent1].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], [Extent1].[LastName] AS [LastName], [Extent1].[MobilePhone] AS [MobilePhone], [Extent1].[SecondaryPhone] AS [SecondaryPhone], [Extent1].[Email] AS [Email], [Extent1].[Location] AS [Location], [Extent1].[StreetAddress] AS [StreetAddress], [Extent1].[City] AS [City], [Extent1].[State] AS [State], [Extent1].[ZIPCode] AS [ZIPCode], [Extent1].[Country] AS [Country], [Extent1].[IdentificationNumber] AS [IdentificationNumber], [Extent1].[Age] AS [Age], [Extent1].[StatusID] AS [StatusID], [Extent1].[UserID] AS [UserID], [Extent1].[ForwardToEmpDateTime] AS [ForwardToEmpDateTime], [Extent1].[ForwardToEmpDifference] AS [ForwardToEmpDifference], [Extent1].[LeadOpenedFirstTime] AS [LeadOpenedFirstTime], [Extent1].[EmpResponseDifference] AS [EmpResponseDifference], [Extent1].[isClient] AS [isClient], [Extent1].[isMeetingSet] AS [isMeetingSet], [Extent1].[isMeetingHeld] AS [isMeetingHeld], [Extent1].[NotesToLeadProvider] AS [NotesToLeadProvider], [Extent1].[NotesFromLeadProvider] AS [NotesFromLeadProvider], [Extent1].[isSuccessfullyInterfaced] AS [isSuccessfullyInterfaced], [Extent1].[InterfacedSystemLeadPK] AS [InterfacedSystemLeadPK], [Extent1].[utm_source] AS [utm_source], [Extent1].[utm_medium] AS [utm_medium], [Extent1].[utm_term] AS [utm_term], [Extent1].[utm_content] AS [utm_content], [Extent1].[utm_campaign] AS [utm_campaign], [Extent1].[ClickId] AS [ClickId], [Extent1].[LastUpdateDateTime] AS [LastUpdateDateTime], [Extent1].[BecameClientDateTime] AS [BecameClientDateTime], [Extent1].[isQuote] AS [isQuote], [Extent1].[isDNC] AS [isDNC], [Extent1].[isSentToDialer] AS [isSentToDialer], [Extent1].[isSentToCRM] AS [isSentToCRM], [Extent1].[CRMLeadID] AS [CRMLeadID], [Extent1].[isQuoteViewed] AS [isQuoteViewed], [Extent1].[GeneralField1] AS [GeneralField1], [Extent1].[GeneralField2] AS [GeneralField2], [Extent1].[BusinessName] AS [BusinessName], [Extent1].[YearInBusiness] AS [YearInBusiness], [Extent1].[MonthlyGross] AS [MonthlyGross], [Extent1].[CreditCardSales] AS [CreditCardSales], [Extent1].[AskingAmount] AS [AskingAmount], [Extent1].[AgeOfYoungestDriver] AS [AgeOfYoungestDriver], [Extent1].[CarInsuranceType] AS [CarInsuranceType], [Extent1].[Manufacturer] AS [Manufacturer], [Extent1].[Model] AS [Model], [Extent1].[Year] AS [Year], [Extent1].[NumberOfClaims] AS [NumberOfClaims], [Extent1].[Experience] AS [Experience], [Extent1].[LicenseRevocation] AS [LicenseRevocation], [Extent1].[InsuranceStartDate] AS [InsuranceStartDate], [Extent1].[VehicleType] AS [VehicleType], [Extent1].[PolicyNumber] AS [PolicyNumber], [Extent1].[PermissionGroup] AS [PermissionGroup], [Extent1].[PastInsurance] AS [PastInsurance], [Extent1].[PropertyClaims] AS [PropertyClaims], [Extent1].[InjuryClaims] AS [InjuryClaims], [Extent1].[LeviCode] AS [LeviCode], [Extent1].[KmPerYear] AS [KmPerYear], [Extent1].[Block] AS [Block], [Extent1].[Owner] AS [Owner], [Extent1].[Usage] AS [Usage], [Extent1].[lien] AS [lien], [Extent1].[Riders] AS [Riders], [Extent1].[CarRegistrationNumber] AS [CarRegistrationNumber], [Extent1].[RegistrationNumber] AS [RegistrationNumber], [Extent1].[DateOfIncident] AS [DateOfIncident], [Extent1].[ClaimNumber] AS [ClaimNumber], [Extent1].[AppraisersName] AS [AppraisersName], [Extent1].[GarageName] AS [GarageName], [Extent1].[ThirdPartyInsuranceCompany] AS [ThirdPartyInsuranceCompany], [Extent1].[HomeInsuranceType] AS [HomeInsuranceType], [Extent1].[SumContent] AS [SumContent], [Extent1].[SumStructure] AS [SumStructure], [Extent1].[Floor] AS [Floor], [Extent1].[Sum] AS [Sum], [Extent1].[LoanRequestAmount] AS [LoanRequestAmount], [Extent1].[LoanPurpose] AS [LoanPurpose], [Extent1].[EmploymentStatus] AS [EmploymentStatus], [Extent1].[Income] AS [Income], [Extent1].[isCreditCard] AS [isCreditCard], [Extent1].[isChecksReturned] AS [isChecksReturned], [Extent1].[LoanAmount] AS [LoanAmount], [Extent1].[Phase] AS [Phase], [Extent1].[MortgageStartIn] AS [MortgageStartIn], [Extent1].[MortgageInsuranceType] AS [MortgageInsuranceType], [Extent1].[StructureType] AS [StructureType], [Extent1].[Floor1] AS [Floor1], [Extent1].[SquareMeters] AS [SquareMeters], [Extent1].[CurrentInsuranceCompany] AS [CurrentInsuranceCompany], [Extent1].[Discriminator] AS [Discriminator], [Extent1].[Provider_ProviderID] AS [Provider_ProviderID], [Extent1].[Company_CompanyID] AS [Company_CompanyID1], [Extent3].[Company_CompanyID] AS [Company_CompanyID2]
        FROM   [dbo].[Leads] AS [Extent1]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Campaigns] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[CampaignID] = [Extent2].[CampaignID]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Providers] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[ProviderID] = [Extent3].[ProviderID]
        WHERE ([Extent1].[Discriminator] IN (N'BasicLead',N'BusinessLoanLead',N'CarInsuranceLead_He',N'ClaimLead_He',N'HomeInsuranceLead_He',N'InvestmentLead',N'LoanLead_He',N'MortgageLead_He',N'MortgageInsuranceLead_He',N'Lead')) AND (0 = [Extent1].[isSentToDialer]) AND ([Extent1].[StatusID] IS NULL) ) AS [Filter1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Campaigns] AS [Extent4] ON [Filter1].[CampaignID1] = [Extent4].[CampaignID]
    WHERE ([Filter1].[InsertionDateTime] > @p__linq__0) AND ([Filter1].[Company_CompanyID2] = @p__linq__1) AND (([Filter1].[UserID] IS NULL) OR ([Filter1].[UserID] = @p__linq__2) OR (([Filter1].[UserID] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__2 IS NULL)))
)  AS [Project1]
ORDER BY [Project1].[InsertionDateTime] ASC
```

Comment: .NET 6 is .NET *Core* 6, not .NET Framework 4+2. EF Core 6 has no relation to EF 6, it's actually 6 versions newer. It's not slower either - the queries are executed by the *database*, not the client. As long as the same query is generated, performance will be the same.

Comment: As for what's wrong here, all the relevant information is missing - no table schemas, no indexes, not even a description of the data. The `Column` attributes don't affect performance, they only affect mapping from a table column to a property. Something your older code did too. `Column` isn't new, it was introduced in EF 4 if not earlier. Use SQL Server's Extended Evens or Profiler to check the actual query and its execution plan. You can also log the query generated by this LINQ query and check its performance. Perhaps some indexes are missing?

Comment: If you depend on `isSentToDialer` to filter lots of data, performance will be bad because indexing boolean data isn't very selective. When a filter will match 50% of the data, the server won't even bother with indexes, it will just scan the entire table. That's not an EF issue

Comment: In both cases compare execution plan.  Also if Model is huge, you may find first query slow, because of Model initialisation.

Comment: I just monitored the SQL server and figured our that the SQL query that is rendered from 2 same linq queries are different. completely. though they both return the same result - the one that is generated from the older version take half the time

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the models, it's a little tricky to help.

However, it seems like the upgrade to EF Core 6 added 2 left joins: Status and Users.

You might be able to avoid them by changing the references to l.Status and l.User to their respective Ids. Example:

```cs
List<Lead> RelevantLeads = (from l in db.Leads.Include("Campaign")
                            where l.InsertionDateTime > fromDateMonths
                                && l.Campaign.Provider.Company.CompanyID == companyId
                                && l.StatusID == null // from l.Status
                                && (l.UserID == null || l.UserID == user.UserID) // from l.User
                                && l.isSentToDialer == false
                            select l).OrderBy(l => l.InsertionDateTime).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks @ESG. I tried your suggestion. It did removed the 2 Left joins though it had a minimal impact on the execution time.